# MS Exchange Server and LDAP

Tags: ldap, exchange-server

I am learning now Exchange Server and how to interface it, so my questions may sound a bit vague or slily.

What is the relation between the Exchange Server and the LDAP server?

Exchange Server uses directory services and LDAP intefaces them. Does that mean that Exchange Server is using LDAP to implement its functionality?

Also, when using LDAP I have to authenticate myself.

What is the relation between this authentication and the authentication when I want to read my mail from ExchangeServer?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Exchange Server is a messaging solution which holds and manipulates the user's email messages and routes them to appropriate client. AD or LDAP server is an authentication server which holds the user's credentials and authorizes the users to use messaging solution.

Both are interconnected to each other and work together to provide authorized user email messages.

When we read mail from Exchange Server, LDAP server authenticates us and Exchange Server provides us the related mailbox content.

There is nothing inside of Exchange Server related to authentication, so AD or LDAP server is necessary for all this stuff.